# CSS unordered list item not fully occupying unorderedlist

Tags: html, css

I've basically created a drop down menu using `<ul>` and `<li>` with `<li>` items ordered vertically. The `<li>` items however don't fully occupy the `<ul>`, There is a vertical bar of unoccupied space at the left. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin`, `padding` and `border`, the box-model propeties.

Answer (score 0):

that could be css margin or padding on the `li`. post an example of your code so we can see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Margin and Padding of the elements.

try:

```
ul, li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

or try:

```
ul{
    display: inline;
}
```